# rpc server return result char will get segment fault

Tags: c++, c, linux, rpc

```
my rpc_telnet.x is below,
01 
02 struct rpc_telnet_data { 
03     string user_id<50>;
04 }; 
05  
06 struct rpc_result { 
07     string msg<50>;
08    
09 }; 
10  
11 program RPC_TELNET_PROG { 
12     version RPC_TELNET_VERS { 
13         rpc_result RPC_TEST(rpc_telnet_data) = 1;
14  
15     } = 1; 
16 } = 0x23451112;


}; 

program RPC_TELNET_PROG { 
version RPC_TELNET_VERS { 
    rpc_result RPC_TEST(rpc_telnet_data) = 1;

} = 1; 
} = 0x23451112;
```

`

```
------------------------
```

when sever side return is integer(I setup integer version rpc_telnet.x ) , it's work perfectly.
but when sever side return result is string(char*),it will get segment fault.
so ,how could I set up return char(result->msg ) properly?
below it's my sever side code.

```
rpc_telnet_server.c
 ------------------------------------------------
01 /*
02  * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
03  * These are only templates and you can use them
04  * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
05  */
06 
07 #include "rpc_telnet.h"
08 
09 bool_t
10 rpc_test_1_svc(rpc_telnet_data *argp, rpc_result *result, struct svc_req *rqstp)
11 {
12  bool_t retval=1;
13     cout << (*argp).user_id << endl;
14     result->msg = "kk";
15  /*
16   * insert server code here
17   */
18 
19  return (retval);
20 }
21 
22 int
23 rpc_telnet_prog_1_freeresult(SVCXPRT *transp, xdrproc_t xdr_result, caddr_t result)
24 {
25      
26  (void) xdr_free(xdr_result, result);
27 
28  /*
29   * Insert additional freeing code here, if needed
30   */
31 
32 }


    rpc_telnet_svc.c
------------------------------------------------

001  /*
002   * Please do not edit this file.
003   * It was generated using rpcgen.
004   */
005  
006  #include "rpc_telnet.h"
007  #include <stdio.h>
008  #include <stdlib.h> /* getenv, exit */
009  #include <rpc/pmap_clnt.h> /* for pmap_unset */
010  #include <string.h> /* strcmp */
011  #include <rpc/rpc_com.h>
012  #include <fcntl.h> /* open */
013  #include <unistd.h> /* fork / setsid */
014  #include <sys/types.h>
015  #include <string.h>
016  #include <sys/resource.h> /* rlimit */
017  #include <syslog.h>
018  
019  #ifdef DEBUG
020  #define    RPC_SVC_FG
021  #endif
022  
023  void
024  rpc_telnet_prog_1(struct svc_req *rqstp, SVCXPRT *transp)
025  {
026     union {
027         rpc_telnet_data rpc_test_1_arg;
028     } argument;
029     union {
030         rpc_result rpc_test_1_res;
031     } result;
032     bool_t retval;
033     xdrproc_t xdr_argument, xdr_result;
034     bool_t (*local)(char *, void *, struct svc_req *);
035  
036     switch (rqstp->rq_proc) {
037     case NULLPROC:
038         (void) svc_sendreply(transp,
039             (xdrproc_t) xdr_void, (char *)NULL);
040         return;
041  
042     case RPC_TEST:
043         xdr_argument = (xdrproc_t) xdr_rpc_telnet_data;
044         xdr_result = (xdrproc_t) xdr_rpc_result;
045         local = (bool_t (*) (char *,  void *,  struct svc_req *))rpc_test_1_svc;
046         break;
047  
048     default:
049         svcerr_noproc(transp);
050         return;
051     }
052     (void) memset((char *)&argument, 0, sizeof (argument));
053     if (!svc_getargs(transp, xdr_argument, (char *)(caddr_t) &argument)) {
054         svcerr_decode(transp);
055         return;
056     }
057     retval = (bool_t) (*local)((char *)&argument, (void *)&result, rqstp);
058  
059     
060    
061  if (retval > 0 && !svc_sendreply(transp, xdr_result, (char *)&result)) {
062         
063         svcerr_systemerr(transp);
064     }
065     
066     if (!svc_freeargs(transp, xdr_argument, (char *)(caddr_t) &argument)) {
067         fprintf(stderr, "unable to free arguments");
068         exit(1);
069     }
070    

075  
076     if (!rpc_telnet_prog_1_freeresult(transp, xdr_result,(char *) (caddr_t) &result))
077         fprintf(stderr, "unable to free results");
078         
079       cout << "rpc_telnet_prog_1_freeresult end" << endl;
080      
081     return;
082  }
083  
084  int
085  main()
086  {
087     pid_t pid;
088     int i;
089  #ifndef RPC_SVC_FG
090         int size;
091         struct rlimit rl;
092         pid = fork();
093         if (pid < 0) {
094             perror("cannot fork");
095             exit(1);
096         }
097         if (pid)
098             exit(0);
099         rl.rlim_max = 0;
100         getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl);
101         if ((size = rl.rlim_max) == 0)
102             exit(1);
103         for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
104             (void) close(i);
105         i = open("/dev/console", 2);
106         (void) dup2(i, 1);
107         (void) dup2(i, 2);
108         setsid();
109         openlog("rpc_telnet", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);
110  #endif
111     if (!svc_create(rpc_telnet_prog_1, RPC_TELNET_PROG, RPC_TELNET_VERS, "netpath")) {
112         fprintf(stderr, "unable to create (RPC_TELNET_PROG, RPC_TELNET_VERS) for netpath.");
113         exit(1);
114     }
115  
116     svc_run();
117     fprintf(stderr, "svc_run returned");
118     exit(1);
119     /* NOTREACHED */
120  }


gdb ./rpc_telnet_server
---------------------
bt
  01  [New LWP 100114]
02  [New Thread 28404300 (LWP 100114/rpc_telnet_server)]
03  55
04  
05  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
06  [Switching to Thread 28404300 (LWP 100114/rpc_telnet_server)]
07  0x2822b584 in free () from /lib/libc.so.7
08  (gdb) bt
09  #0  0x2822b584 in free () from /lib/libc.so.7
10  #1  0x2824ad2a in xdr_string () from /lib/libc.so.7
11  #2  0x08048ec0 in xdr_rpc_result (xdrs=0x284821c8, objp=0xbfbfd514)
12      at rpc_telnet_xdr.c:21
13  #3  0x28238be3 in svc_create () from /lib/libc.so.7
14  #4  0x08048c4e in rpc_telnet_prog_1 (rqstp=0xbfbfd598, transp=0x28238be3)
15      at rpc_telnet_svc.c:71
16  #5  0x2823cfd8 in svc_getreq_common () from /lib/libc.so.7
17  #6  0x2823d541 in svc_getreqset () from /lib/libc.so.7
18  #7  0x281dbb64 in svc_run () from /lib/libc.so.7
19  #8  0x08048b3f in main () at rpc_telnet_svc.c:116


01  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -D_THEAD_SAF -c rpc_telnet_clnt.c
02  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -D_THEAD_SAF -c rpc_telnet_client.c
03  rpc_telnet_client.c: In function 'void rpc_telnet_prog_1(char*)':
04  rpc_telnet_client.c:18: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'har*'
05  rpc_telnet_client.c:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'har*'
06  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -D_THEAD_SAF -c rpc_telnet_xdr.c
07  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o rpc_telnet_client  rpc_telnet_cln.o rpc_telnet_client.o rpc_telnet_xdr.o -pthread
08  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -D_THEAD_SAF -c rpc_telnet_svc.c
09  rpc_telnet_svc.c: In function 'int main()':
10  rpc_telnet_svc.c:87: warning: unused variable 'pid'
11  rpc_telnet_svc.c:88: warning: unused variable 'i'
12  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -pipe  -D_REENTRANT -D_THEAD_SAF -c rpc_telnet_server.c
13  rpc_telnet_server.c: In function 'bool_t rpc_test_1_svc(rpc_telnet_data*, rpc_reult*, svc_req*)':
14  rpc_telnet_server.c:14: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'har*'
15  rpc_telnet_server.c: At global scope:
16  rpc_telnet_server.c:10: warning: unused parameter 'rqstp'
17  rpc_telnet_server.c:23: warning: unused parameter 'transp'
18  rpc_telnet_server.c: In function 'int rpc_telnet_prog_1_freeresult(SVCXPRT*, boo_t (*)(XDR*, ...), char*)':
19  rpc_telnet_server.c:32: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
20  g++ -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o rpc_telnet_server  rpc_telnet_svco rpc_telnet_server.o rpc_telnet_xdr.o -pthread
```

Comment: I see you fail to initialize some local variables before you use them. For example `retval` in the `rpc_test_1_svc` function. Uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value and using them (for example by returning it) leads to *undefined behavior*. Undefined behavior, it doesn't matter where it is, makes your whole program practically invalid. Try building with more warnings enabled (e.g `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when building with GCC or Clang), and fix the root cause of the warnings you get, as warnings are often an indication of you doing something suspect or weird.

Comment: Furthermore, `rpc_telnet_prog_1_freeresult` is declared as returning an `int` but doesn't return anything at all, another case of *undefined behavior*. If this is your actual code, you need to fix these problems, if this is not your actual code, you need to explicitly tell us that, and what problems in the code to disregard. Better yet, instead of showing incomplete code, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Regarding your debugger backtrace, can you please indicate which line 71 in `rpc_telnet_svc.c` is? It's very hard for us to find it otherwise.

Comment: And just a thought, are you sure you could use any pointer for your strings? Maybe you should try to allocate memory dynamically and copy the string into that memory, and use the pointer to the allocated memory instead?

Comment: thanks your advise, I recoding and initialize `retval=1`,compile with -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. line 71 in rpc_telnet_svc.c is svc_freeargs. (line 061 svc_sendreply)seem will send reply the result to client and  my client  will  get segment fault too at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before I asked question,I had been tested code,google, weekly.
finally I get right solution.
when server side return type is string and generate template with

```
rpcgen -aM rpc_telnet.x   //-M for multithread purpose
```

1.setup server side return string ex:
in rpc_telnet_server.c -> rpc_test_1_svc function

```
result->msg =  (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
strcpy(result->msg,"888");
```

2.setup client side return string ex:
in rpc_telnet_client.c -> rpc_telnet_prog_1 function

```
result_1.msg = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
strcpy(result_1.msg,"");
```

template generate xdr_free() will free malloc for you.